# User Exception Tomcat OK -> Websphere NOK

Tags: java, web-services

I am very new to Java and I try to understand user exceptions in webservices.

Now, I have copied the following example to Netbeans: http://mprabhat.com/2014/11/03/744/

I am using jax-ws 2.2 and java 1.6

In this classes I have delete @Stateless and build it. Alright. It works ... And the deploy to the local TomcatEE works too. I get a user exception.

BUT ... I use this war file and put in on Websphere 8.5.5 Server. I get the excpetion "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/xml/ws/WebFault.messageName()Ljava/lang/String;" I have no idea, what the problem is.

Can you help me ??

Thank you

Comment: Are you *certain* that Websphere is using jax-ws 2.2 and not some earlier version?

Answer (score 1):

Library mismatch. The version of the library that was used to compile had the method `WebFault.messageName()` (returning String), but the version that was used to run.

Therefore the code is trying to call the method that is no longer present -> `NoSuchMethodError`.

Possible and likely reason for this is that WebSphere has its own version of the library.

Comment: You could replace the version that WebSphere is using with the correct one, hoping that won't break anything else. This is a bit advanced, so if you're new to Java it might be hard for you. I recommend lots of googling.